# Cast int to string in where clause

Tags: sql-server

I' ve got a query that cast int file to date and it's working ok. But when I add this  cast to where then my query not working

```
select 
 convert(date,CONVERT(varchar(10),t.TimeEntityElementId,101))  
from dbo.Time t
where  
  convert(date,CONVERT(varchar(10),t.TimeEntityElementId,101))  < N'2019-01-01'
```

Comment: What does "not working" mean? Unexpected results, an error, something else..? If `TimeEntityElementId` is an `int` then what is the style code `101` for in the`varchar` `CONVERT` expression? I'm guessing it should be part of the conversion to `date`, not `varchar`. Ideally, however, you want to avoid converting your columns in your `WHERE`; it makes the query non-SARGable which can have (severe) effects on your query's performance. This has the feel of an XY question, and I think we'd be better off with sample data and expected results so that we can show you how to make this query SARGable.

Comment: What do the `TimeEntityElementId` values look like? I may be able to suggest a _**much**_ more efficient option.

Comment: It's for example 20190114 or 20160529

Comment: @adamek339 I know it's stale now, but I just saw you responded. I have an answer now.

Answer (score 0):

Why not just use `cast()` ? :

```
select cast(t.TimeEntityElementId as date)
from dbo.Time t
where cast(t.TimeEntityElementId as date)  < '2019-01-01';
```

`N` is not appropriate for that because `TimeEntityElementId` has `datetime` type & `N` stands for "National language character set" which means that you are passing an `NCHAR`, `NVARCHAR` or `NTEXT` type data.

Comment: Because an `int` can't be directly cast to a `date`; only `datetime` supports direct conversion from an `int`. `SELECT CONVERT(date,0);` returns an error, as does an "integer representation" of a date like `SELECT CONVERT(date, 20170116)`;

Answer (score 0):

So it appears we have an `int` value where you really need a `DateTime`. Correcting this in the table definition will really save you a **LOT** of trouble. But in this case we can still improve some things with the existing data.

Start with this WHERE condition:

```
convert(date,CONVERT(varchar(10),t.TimeEntityElementId,101))  < N'2019-01-01'
```

The use of the `CONVERT()` functions here prevents using any index you may have for `TimeEntityElementId`. Instead, we can take advantage of values with segments organized in good ordinal size and position. This is similar to how Sql Server actually stores Dates/Datetimes, but it carves a 10,000 number chunk from the integer space per year rather then just 365, as Sql Server does. It means you can greatly reduce the code and write the same condition as a simple numeric comparison, like this:

```
t.TimeEntityElementId  < 20190101
```

This does not need to do any per-row conversions and can still use a `TimeEntityElementId` index, and so should perform **MUCH** faster, potentially multiple orders of magnitude.

Of course, you still need to worry about the SELECT side, but now you're only converting rows that pass the WHERE clause, rather than every row in the table, and that may be enough to fix the problem. But we can do more. We can also remove the SELECT conversion using the `DATEFROMPARTS()` function:

```
 DATEFROMPARTS(t.TimeEntityElementId/10000, (t.TimeEntityElementId % 10000) / 100, t.TimeEntityElementId % 100)
```

This avoids the need to parse the string to a datetime, which is actually quite a slow operation. As crazy at the above expression is, it's all math, which the CPU can do very efficiently. Parsing a string has to account for all kinds of cultural/internationalization quirks, and therefore tends to be much slower. It's also less sensitive to the case where `TimeEntityElementId` has rows which don't conform to the date format. You could still get weird results there, but at least it shouldn't just fail the whole query.

Put it all together like this:

```
SELECT
    DATEFROMPARTS(t.TimeEntityElementId/10000, (t.TimeEntityElementId % 10000) / 100, t.TimeEntityElementId % 100)  
FROM dbo.Time t
WHERE t.TimeEntityElementId  < 20190101
```

But these are mainly performance improvements. They are likely to also solve your problem, but only as a side effect, and I can't know for sure because we don't have a clear description of what went wrong.

Which brings me to the last point. We need a better idea of what "doesn't work" means. "Doesn't work" without additional explanation of an error or flawed behavior is **never** good enough.